# How does LD_PRELOAD='/something/$LIB/libmyx.so' myprogram expand under different conditions?

Tags: linux

I am running into errors finding the correct library

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/$LIB/libwisktrack.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

My libraries are setup as follows

```
bash-4.4$ ls -alR /ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/
/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/:
total 36
drwxr-xr-x.  6 sarvi eng  4096 Sep 23 22:46 .
drwxr-xr-x. 88 sarvi eng 16384 Sep 23 22:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 sarvi eng  4096 Sep 23 22:56 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 sarvi eng  4096 Sep 23 22:56 lib32
drwxr-xr-x.  2 sarvi eng  4096 Sep 23 22:56 lib64

/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib:
total 29452
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:46 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 sarvi eng 30024352 Sep 23 22:38 libwisktrack.so

/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib32:
total 29428
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:46 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 sarvi eng 30003020 Sep 23 22:56 libwisktrack.so

/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib64:
total 28792
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 sarvi eng     4096 Sep 23 22:46 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 sarvi eng 29349680 Sep 23 22:56 libwisktrack.so
bash-4.4$ 
bash-4.4$ file /ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib/libwisktrack.so 
/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib/libwisktrack.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c38570777cfc99005a4693f68adf1014b7d647fd, with debug_info, not stripped, too many notes (256)
bash-4.4$ file /ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib32/libwisktrack.so 
/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib32/libwisktrack.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=be90026de8fad17a99582991f1983e321a17ea87, with debug_info, not stripped, too many notes (256)
bash-4.4$ file /ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib64/libwisktrack.so 
/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/lib64/libwisktrack.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=223ca6c07b59b940355a3ca8299df8f68743c22a, with debug_info, not stripped, too many notes (256)
bash-4.4$
```

From what I can tell my library installation of 32 and 64 bit versions of my libwisktrack.so are installed right.

When i compile my own testprog32 and testprog64 they seem to load the respective libraries correctly

```
bash-4.4$ file tests/testprog32 
tests/testprog32: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a9db0c61d648adf715a79c5cfb7b06f6a128b90e, not stripped
bash-4.4$ LD_PRELOAD='/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/$LIB/libwisktrack.so' tests/testprog32
Constructor: 92729
testprog running......
Command: takes one argument. Which system call to run
Options: readlink, vprintf, printf, open, fopen, creat

bash-4.4$ file tests/testprog64
tests/testprog64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=fbb14df720b2997c56995c98b2ad28734f554bb9, not stripped
bash-4.4$ LD_PRELOAD='/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/$LIB/libwisktrack.so' tests/testprog64
Constructor: 92349
testprog running......
Command: takes one argument. Which system call to run
Options: readlink, vprintf, printf, open, fopen, creat
```

Yet this program has trouble find the right library and seems to pick up the wrong library

```
bash-4.4$ file /nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/usr/bin/protoc
/nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/usr/bin/protoc: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f52e087673df429ad5849877b08d89b080e934c2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
bash-4.4$ 

bash-4.4$ LD_PRELOAD='/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/$LIB/libwisktrack.so' /nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/usr/bin/protoc
ERROR: ld.so: object '/ws/sarvi-sjc/cel8root/$LIB/libwisktrack.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Usage: /nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/usr/bin/protoc [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
```

What am I missing here?

One difference I notice between the 64 bit testprog64 and the failing 64 bit program is

```
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Vs 
interpreter /nobackup/sarvi/xrwisktest/binos/linkfarm/host/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-xesdk-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Not sure how that maters

Update:
strace shows it opening the following file for a 64 bit program invocation, which doesnt make sense to me

```
open("/ws/sarvi-sjc/wisktrack/cel8root/lib/libwisktrack.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Shouldn't this be opening one of the lib64 or lib/x86_64 or lib/x86_64-linux-gnu paths ?

Just to be clear, I don't want to use LD_LIBRRY_PATH, as I ran into use cases where some programs/scripts, explicitly disallow the setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, for example "python setup.py install" I found in a SDK.

So I looking to make this work without having to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. "$LIB" to work consistently work is the only option i am aware of.

Mine is a RHEL8 development host. The specific program that is running into a problem extracted from an SDK compiled for the host to build other cross compiling programs as art of a very large build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$LIB` documentation from `ld.so` man:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

> ```
>    $LIB (or equivalently ${LIB})
>           This expands to lib or lib64 depending on the architecture
>           (e.g., on x86-64, it expands to lib64 and on x86-32, it
>           expands to lib).
> ```

This is not completely true and actual values can be different. E.g. you are running a nativesdk binary from OpenEmbedded SDK. As you've noticed the SDK uses its own `ld.so`. That `ld.so` is not configured for multilib support and it expects to have only one `lib` directory with 64-bit libraries. That's why it resolves `$LIB` to `lib`.

You can see default library directory definition (`BASELIB`) here:
http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n12

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian system I created a mini `.so` with a ((constructor)) routine
that writes a message and confirmed the .ctor output with this setup:

64-bit lib:   `$HOME/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ctor.so`
`LD_PRELOAD='$LIB/ctor.so' /bin/echo`

The longer answer in this [relate posting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36849507/10304821)
provides details with 32- vs 64-bit
and runtime linker use of different subdirs with various distros.

Comment: as I have explained. strace shows it looking for ``` open("/ws/sarvi-sjc/wisktrack/cel8root/lib/libwisktrack.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)open("/ws/sarvi-sjc/wisktrack/cel8root/lib/libwisktrack.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)``` on a 64 bit machine, whch doesnt match anything i am reading

Comment: The above example uses a relative path; related content in the linked posting suggests setting LD_PRELOAD with a relative pathname instead of absolute; maybe provide  LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well; might need to adjust your subdirs based on new results from `strace`. What is your Linux distro and version?

Comment: The build host is RHEL8 and the ld.so seems to map $LIB to lib for 32 bit annd lib64 for 64 bit. for binaries built for the host. But the build system also uses an SDK that yocto/open-embedded. That executables within that extractd sdk seem to be using its own ld.so that seems to map $LIB to lib on that same 64 bit host.      So unless I look up what executable I am going to run and know which ld.so it is going to use, from host or from the SDK inside the build system, I can't be sure what $LIB will map to