# How to apply LD_PRELOAD only to target program?

Tags: c, x86, heap-memory, elf, ld-preload

I am trying to debug a Heap Corruption (using the QIRA Debugger); that only works with Doug Lea's Malloc.

I have tried doing the following:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./malloc.so qira ./program $(cat shfree5)
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: ld.so: object './malloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

which happens because the loader tries linking an x86 `malloc.so` to an x64 `qira`.

I want to apply the `LD_PRELOAD` only to `./program`, not to `qira`; I have tried with the `env` command, but can not make it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't find detailed qira documentation, but you need to start qira, set the environment variable in there, then start your program.

Comment: Unfortunately, the handling of all of the  `LD_*` environment variables on Linux fails miserably in a mixed 32/64-bit environment.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849507/using-ld-preload-mixed-64bit-32bit-environment-in-linux/36851082 for some things that might help.

Comment: `env LD_PRELOAD=./malloc.so ./program ...` should work *if* you have an implementation of `env` that works under `qira`.

Comment: "I am trying to debug a Heap Corruption" -- you will likely get _much_ further by using Address Sanitizer instead of `LD_PRELOAD`ing debug `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can set `QEMU_SET_ENV=LD_PRELOAD=./malloc.so` in the environment to affect the process.

I'll note that you can similarly unset environment variables for the target by setting `QEMU_UNSET_ENV=FOO,BAR`.

Comment: @Joshua: A little more what? Qira uses QEMU. I tested by running it against env with a fake .so file, which gave me an error from ld.so, showing that it used that set value.

Comment: I added the word environment to my answer, since it apparently wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work, dynamically linked now!